# Pass read() contents to C++ string type

Tags: c++, string, system-calls

I am using mystr.c_str() function to call write(), open(), etc system calls which need a char* argument. Though because of the nature of .c_str() being a function I suppose call read(rfd, &mystr.c_str(), mystr.lenght()) will not work. What is the best/fast way of implementing this without temporary using char* str?

Comment: `string.c_str()` __should__ work. Just skip the `&`.

Comment: My comment is talking about using `c_str()` for the `iostream::open()` function tho. I somehow overlooked you also want `write`. In that case - you'll have to use a buffer of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write directly into the buffer of an `std::string`, as it only ever returns char pointers that point to a read-only string<sup>1</sup>.  Consider using a local array as a buffer.  This is about as optimal as you can get without invoking undefined behavior.

```
const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

ssize_t chars_read = read(rfd, buffer, BUFFER_SIZE);

if (chars_read > 0) {
    // To create a new string:
    std::string read_string(buffer, chars_read);

    // To populate an existing string:
    existing_string.assign(buffer, chars_read);
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> At least pre-C++11.  In C++11 it is safe to use `&some_string[0]` to get a mutable pointer to the string, but you should ensure that you don't write to `&some_string[some_string.size()]` or beyond, as this will invoke UB, so you would want to `resize()` the string first.

Comment: data is const: `const char* data() const;`, I would not recomend reading binary data to std::string, better use vector: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/

Comment: @marcin_j So it is, somehow I overlooked that.  Updated answer to use a char array as a buffer, which is about the best you can do in this situation.

Comment: Can't you do `&str[0]`? In C++11 the string is required to be stored in contiguous memory.

Comment: @Jay Can you safely increment that pointer without invoking UB though?

Comment: Yeah, why couldn't you?

Comment: @Jay You can increment the pointer but is this guaranteed to be safe?  What if it's C++ < 11?

Comment: Well you can always increment the pointer at least once, no matter what version of C++. But pre-C++11, strings were not required to be contiguous, but nobody knows any implementations that use non-contiguous strings. I guess we should use either your way or a vector then if you don't know that you're going to have C++11.

Comment: @Jay I've updated my answer to provide C++11-specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

It is not allowed, but it will **mostly** work (with a `const_cast`) for most if not all implementations of `string`, although some implementations will have very very surprising side effects.

Because you are not allowed to write directly to the string returned by `c_str()`, that allows implementations of string to optimize in various ways. One particular implementation of `string` I've come accross internally uses a reference counted pointer for copies (only if the size of the string is large). So if you copy the string and then illegally overwrite it's contents, both the original and the copy change.

Even if the `string` implementation you are currently using survives such abuse, it might later be changed, at which point the program magically starts working in strange ways.

Comment: tl;dr version of this answer is "it's undefined behavior, don't do it."

Comment: Might note that in C++11 copy-on-write strings are not standard-conforming.

Comment: actually it's "the behaviour is defined by the string implementation you are using and may change whenever you change/upgrade your libraries, have fun!"

Comment: "Might note that in C++11 copy-on-write strings are not standard-conforming" - did that ever stop library writers? ;) Good catch tough!

Comment: @Peter "defined by the implementation" is the same as "undefined."  The standard says you can't do it, and therefore implementations don't have to assume you can.  So yes, it is undefined behavior.  That's why you avoid it.

Comment: "defined by the implementation" is the same as "undefined." - I happen to disagree strongly with such a general statement. I'd agree that "defined by the implementation" is the same as "undefined by the standard", and that using implementation specific details should be be avoided "when possible". In the context of this question avoiding them is certainly possible.